# QCharts - create a break (null value) in QLineSeries

Tags: c++, qt, graph, line, qchart

I am currently using `QLineSeries` to represent a temperature-over-time relation.

I have a temperature sensor connected. It sends data every minute.

The problem is, that the measurements are made in 20-minute periods after which the sensor is inactive for 60 minutes.

I indicate the start of a new series by setting the temperature value to `-0xff`.
Now, how can I create a Graph with `QtCharts` that has a null value?

Right now even if I pass the value of `-0xff` to be drawn on the graph, it just draws it. I want it to stop drawing the currently started line and create a new one whenever a new measurement period starts.

Comment: It would help if you could post a MCVE. A piece of code where you send `-0xff` to your `QLineSeries`, what you get displayed and what you would expect.

Answer (score 1):

> I want it to stop drawing the currently started line and create a new one whenever a new measurement period starts.

Then you need to simply add one serie to every line you want to draw. When your sensor sends you `0xff`, just stop populating the current `QLineSeries` and create a new one to draw the next set of data to be received.